# PartialViews - Not Using Shared Site.css in Editor/Display Templates - ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I'm using the [JQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) functionality in my Open Source Project. I'm doing this to learn MVC3 (And various other technologies). Now I've got that all working. The problem is my Partial Views within each tab have links off the the relevant CRUD functionality. I've set these CRUD views up as Display and Editor Templates. Its these that are not picking up the `_Layout.cshtml` references to the Site.css.

**EDIT START**

I've found in the "Add View" scaffolding functionality that when you click the *Create as a partial view* box that the master page functionality disappears, ie greys out, BUT in Razor I thought if this is empty it uses the `_viewstart` file, which loads the_Layout?

**EDIT END**

Here is my **Dashboard.cshtml** code with the JQuery UI Tab logic:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        getContentTab (1);
    });

    function getContentTab(index) {
        var url='@Url.Content("~/SiteAdmin/AjaxGetTab")/' + index;
        var targetDiv = "#tabs-" + index;
        var ajaxLoading = "<img id='ajax-loader' src='@Url.Content("~/Content")/ajax-     loader.gif' align='left' height='28' width='28'>";

        $(targetDiv).html("<p>" + ajaxLoading + " Loading...</p>"); 
        $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: url,
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            $(targetDiv).html(result);
          }
        });           


    }
```

```
   <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="getContentTab(1);">Transaction Type</a>  </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="getContentTab(2);">Direction Type</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3" onclick="getContentTab(3);">User Type</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4" onclick="getContentTab(4);">Currency Type</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my AjaxGetTab Action Method if you need to know how i decide to create tabs and create the list objects:

```
     /// <summary>
    /// AJAX action method to obtain the correct Tab to use.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Tab number</param>
    /// <returns>Partial View</returns>
    public ActionResult AjaxGetTab(int id)
    {
        string partialViewName = string.Empty;
        object model = null;

        //--Decide which view and model to pass back.
        switch (id)
        {
            case 1:
                partialViewName = "_TransactionType";
                model = db.TransactionTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 2:
                partialViewName = "_DirectionType";
                model = db.DirectionTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 3:
                partialViewName = "_UserType";
                model = db.UserTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 4:
                partialViewName = "_CurrencyType";
                model = db.CurrencyTypes.ToList();
                break;
            case 5:
                partialViewName = "_tabError";
                break;

        }


        return PartialView(partialViewName,model);
    }
```

At the moment I'm working on **TransactionType** so here is the `_TransctionType.cshtml` code for the `PartialView`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Accounts.Models.TransactionType>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateTransactionType")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Record Status
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>
    <th>
        Created Date
    </th>
    <th>
        Amended Date
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RecordStatus)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AmendedDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Now the "Edit" & Delete `ActionLink` has an `EditorTemplate` and the Details has a `DisplayTemplate` folder with the required **TransactionType.cshtml** Its these views which the `_Layout` Site.css isnt being applied to. Here is example code from the "Edit" code base:

**_EditTransactionType.cshtml**:

```
@model Accounts.Models.TransactionType
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>

 }
```

And here is the **TransactionType.cshtml** which sits in */Views/SiteAdmin/EditorTemplate*:

```
    @model Accounts.Models.TransactionType
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Transaction Type</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecordStatus)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecordStatus)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecordStatus)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Now I could just put a reference to the Site.css in each Template, but is there a cleaner way of doing this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_ViewStart is only applied to Views that are rendered, this is determined on how you render the view. E.G using RenderPartial or returning a PartialView from a controller returns only the contents (and nest partials) of the PartialView that you are targetting.

If the _LayoutFile applied to every view and every partial view then you would end up with pages like so:

```
<html>
  <head />

  <body>      
    <html>
      <head />     
      <body>
        <!-- Actual Partial View Content -->
      </body>
    </html>    
  </body>
</html>
```

When a page is rendered all of the the _layout, the view to be rendered, any partial views and any nest partials or editor/display templates are built into a single page and returned to the client so any style sheets that are referenced by the _Layout master will be applied to this now flattened heirarchy of (Partial)Views.

Have you inspected the output HTML to make sure that is as expected? It may not be a problem with the views.

Comment: I will let you know tomorrow Marc (I have a wild son high on easter egg sugar at the moment!) and let you know. Thanks for taking the time to reply, appreciated

Comment: Hi Marcus, i changed my controller to return a View instead of a PartialView, and this rendered my review correctly with the correct styling. Ive learnt something new today about HTML and views so thank you. Im amending the above to include the Solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see why you complicated using jqueryui tabs so much adding onclick then a switch etc.

```
 <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("TransactionType", "YourController")"><span>Transaction Type</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("DirectionType", "YourController")"><span>Direction Type</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("UserType", "YourController")"><span>User Type</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("CurrencyType", "YourController")"><span>Currency Type</span></a></li>
       </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabs').tabs({
            spinner: '<img src="../../Content/Images/tabsppinner.gif" alt="" /> @Loading...'
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Then you would just have one controller with actions defined for every tab.

Comment: HI plurby, thanks for the time in posting, i will try a refactor tonight to see if this makes any difference. I was originally following a blog post on learning the JQuery UI Tabs. I have all of my CRUD Methods within ONE Controller (SiteAdmin), which is why i chose this route. Again thanks for looking at this appreciated.